# Selector is selecting all radio buttons in multiple rows. I want to get the name of an input box on the clicked radio buttons row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, radio-button

I have the following layout:

[image: layout diagram]

I am watching for the dollar sign ($) and percent sign (%) radio button changes using the following selector:

```
$( "#facultyTable input:radio.dollar,#facultyTable input:radio.percent").change(function(){
    //What to do here?
});
```

I tried to use a `.parent()` selector however the problem is that since I have all the radio buttons selected I can't simply get the parent `<tr>` of one row, it is off all the rows. What I want is the following: Once a radio button is pressed jquery gets the value of the textbox to the left of it in the same row. How can I achieve this?

Here is the table layout if needed:

```
 <table id="facultyTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Payment Distribution</th>
                <th>Account Number (Optional)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody><tr>
            <td><input name="username[]" value="klarson" data-cip-id="cIPJQ342845639" style="background-image: none; background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: repeat;"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="klarsonOption" value="Even">Even
                <input type="radio" class="dollar" name="klarsonOption" value="$">$
                <input type="radio" class="percent" name="klarsonOption" value="%">%
                <input type="text" name="klarsonAmount" style="display:none;">
                    </td>
            <td><input name="accountNum[]" value="604700-23456-2346-246" data-cip-id="cIPJQ342845640"></td>
            </tr><tr>
            <td><input name="username[]" value="ppoupart" data-cip-id="cIPJQ342845641" style="background-image: none; background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: repeat;"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ppoupartOption" value="Even">Even
                <input type="radio" class="dollar" name="ppoupartOption" value="$">$
                <input type="radio" class="percent" name="ppoupartOption" value="%">%
                <input type="text" name="ppoupartAmount" style="display:none;">
                    </td>
            <td><input name="accountNum[]" value="604700-23456-2346-246" data-cip-id="cIPJQ342845642"></td>
            </tr><tr>
            <td><input name="username[]" value="rcohen" data-cip-id="cIPJQ342845643" style="background-image: none; background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: repeat;"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="rcohenOption" value="Even">Even
                <input type="radio" class="dollar" name="rcohenOption" value="$">$
                <input type="radio" class="percent" name="rcohenOption" value="%">%
                <input type="text" name="rcohenAmount" style="display:none;">
                    </td>
            <td><input name="accountNum[]" value="604700-23456-2346-246" data-cip-id="cIPJQ342845644"></td>
            </tr><tr>
            <td><input name="username[]" value="shai" data-cip-id="cIPJQ342845645" style="background-image: none; background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: repeat;"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="shaiOption" value="Even">Even
                <input type="radio" class="dollar" name="shaiOption" value="$">$
                <input type="radio" class="percent" name="shaiOption" value="%">%
                <input type="text" name="shaiAmount" style="display:none;">
                    </td>
            <td><input name="accountNum[]" value="604700-23456-2346-246" data-cip-id="cIPJQ342845646"></td>
            </tr><tr>
            <td><input name="username[]" value="vanbeek" data-cip-id="cIPJQ342845647" title="Lazarus is saving this form. 
Click to recover previous versions" style="cursor: auto; background-image: none; background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: repeat;"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="vanbeekOption" value="Even">Even
                <input type="radio" class="dollar" name="vanbeekOption" value="$">$
                <input type="radio" class="percent" name="vanbeekOption" value="%">%
                <input type="text" name="vanbeekAmount" style="display:none;">
                    </td>
            <td><input name="accountNum[]" value="604700-23456-2346-246" data-cip-id="cIPJQ342845648"></td>
            </tr></tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
$( "#facultyTable input:radio.dollar,#facultyTable input:radio.percent").change(function(){

    var username = $(this).parent("td").prev("td").find("input:text").val();

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j6V45/1)**

Comment: Thanks, this works, could you explain how this works though? How is the `.prev()` working?